# Equivalent of Powershell [ValidateSet]

Tags: c#, powershell

In Powershell when I define a function I can easily specify a list of possible values for a parameter using `[ValidateSet]`, for example

```
function Log {
    param (
        [ValidateSet("File", "Database")] 
        [string]$Type = "File"
    )
    # my code
}
```

This way I define both a default value `file` and a set of possible values `file` and `database`. Is there a similar way in C# or should I "manually" perform the check in the constructor?

```
public Log(string type = "file") {
    public Log() {
        if ... # here goes my check on the string
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create your own [custom validator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224(v=vs.140).aspx), it will work very similarly to the validate set attribute.  Depending on the technology you are using, you can use [existing ones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707335(v=vs.91).aspx) as well.

Comment: If you have a finite range of values, why not just use an enumeration?

Comment: In the case you provided here, why use strings if there are only 2 options? I believe it would be better to use an Enum instead, then you don't have to validate.

Comment: @MethodMan, I think you made an infinite loop, I'm stuck... (link to this question)

Comment: sorry https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @DavidG please can you provide me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If you have only a finite range of values, then you could use an enumeration instead. First set up your enumeration:

```
public enum MyValues
{
    File,
    Database
}
```

And then use it as you would any other parameter type:

```
public void Log(MyValues type = MyValues.File)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case MyValues.File:
            //Do file stuff here
            break;
        case MyValues.Database:
            //Do database stuff here
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("You passed in a dodgy value!");
    }
}
```